# ServiceMix 5.1 example bundle fails after update

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Exemple `examples\activemq\activemq-camel-blueprint` fails after being updated. My own blueprint bundles also fails in the same conditions.

```
karaf@root> features:install examples-activemq-camel-blueprint
karaf@root> >>>> ActiveMQ-Blueprint-Example set body:  Fri Sep 12 18:11:16 CEST 2014
>>>> ActiveMQ-Blueprint-Example set body:  Fri Sep 12 18:11:18 CEST 2014
>>>> ActiveMQ-Blueprint-Example set body:  Fri Sep 12 18:11:20 CEST 2014

karaf@root> stop 381

[ 381] [Resolved   ] [            ] [       ] [   80] Apache ServiceMix :: Examples :: ActiveMQ Camel Blueprint (5.1.0)

karaf@root> update 381

karaf@root> start 381


18:13:53,156 | ERROR | Thread-65        | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 7 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle activemq-camel-blueprint
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:122)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_45]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:933)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_45]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:230)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:155)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.processProcessors(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:527)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:361)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:276)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:245)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:235)
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1103)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:695)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:483)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4244)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1923)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:931)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.StartBundle.doExecute(StartBundle.java:37)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:37)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:183)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_45]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4.doRun(ShellFactoryImpl.java:144)[47:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:2.3.4]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:135)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_45]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)[:1.7.0_45]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$4.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:133)[47:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:2.3.4]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)[:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)[:1.7.0_45]
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.interfaces.ProxyClassLoader.isInvalid(ProxyClassLoader.java:109)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.interfaces.InterfaceProxyGenerator.getProxyInstance(InterfaceProxyGenerator.java:84)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AsmProxyManager.createNewProxy(AsmProxyManager.java:72)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingInterceptingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createDelegatingProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:40)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.createProxy(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:338)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:106)
        ... 50 more
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... did you manage to find an answer?